# Flask wtform errors rather than field errors

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I understand how to validate each field and show each error if needed. But how do I show a form error.

What I mean is that the user may enter valid info, but the form might be wrong as a whole.

Example:
Form with username and password. Each would have a validator. How can I display an error if the login failed (account doesn't exist or incorrect password)?

I tried raising a ValidationError... but that just raises an error as normal.

```
def login():
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        username = form.username.data
        password = form.password.data

        if login(username, password):
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        else:
            raise ValidationError('Invalid login')

    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 2):

change your `raise ValidationError('Invalid login')` to `flash('Invalid login')`
and remember to `from flask import flash`
then add a field to your 'login.html' to show this message

```
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
<div class="alert alert-warning">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    {{ message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Oh I had forgotten about that. Is that what flash is normally for? It's there any way to send the error through wtforms?

Comment: I usually use this way and you can add the field to your base template,so you can use flash everywhere. I don't know how to do this with wtforms.